# write FSM for for loop in verilog

Tags: verilog, fsm

I want to implement this for loop through a FSM

```
  int j;
   for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
  j++
  }
```

I think 3 states are required: init, increment and done.

init -> initialization
increment -> will increment i/j
done -> final state

my try

```
module fsm(
    clk, z, next_state
);
  input        clk;
  output [7:0] z;
  reg    [7:0] z;
  reg    [7:0] k;
  reg    [7:0] state, next_state;

  parameter S0=0;
  parameter S1=0;
  parameter S2=0; // my confusion lies here

  always @ (*) begin : next_state_logic
    case ( state )
      S0: begin
        k = 'b0;
        z = 'b0;
        next_state = S1;
        //else next_state = S0;
      end
      S1: begin 
        z=z+1;
        k=k+1; 
        if (k<8'b00110010)
          next_state = S1;
        else
          next_state = S2;
      end
      S2: begin
        z=S2;
      end
      default: next_state = S0;
  endcase
end // continued to the right

// continued from left
always @ (posedge clk) begin: state_assignment
  state <= next_state;
end

endmodule
```

I also need to measure number of clock cycle does this loop takes to execute
suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Indenting code makes in much easier to read, and easier for others to help you.

If your not limited to verilog-95 then the port list can be changed from

```
module fsm(
  clk, z
);
input        clk;
output [7:0] z;
reg    [7:0] z;
```

to :

```
module fsm(
  input            clk, 
  output reg [7:0] z
);
```

Your current issue has been in defining states. If you want 3 states you need at least 2 bits. Therefore `reg [1:0] state; reg [1:0] next_state;` would be the minimum widths required.

Your states could be defined as:

```
parameter S0=2'b00;
parameter S1=2'b01;
parameter S2=2'b10;
```

NB: if they are not going to be overridden then make then `localparam`s.

Comment: thanx Morgan, I am done with my FSM Design..now what actually need is to run my FSM module for certain number of time after certain number of delays..so in c i need
  for (i;i<10;i++)
    {
   my FSM;
    sleep(10 ms)
        }
my problem lies , how sleep can be used in verilog
{

Comment: @SangeetSaha sleep does not really have meaning in verilog (lots of parallel hardware). Verilog for design does not really have a concept of time, only clock edges. If you do get stuck well formatted questions do often get a response. So If you have something that you think makes a good question do create another question.